# sd_journal_sendv writing BLOB instead of string

Tags: linux-kernel, systemd-journald

Can please some one explain me how to use sd_journal_sendv system call?
I tried to use with below code snippet but input strings are interpreted as BLOB by journald.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/uio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <systemd/sd-journal.h>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    char buf0[50];
    char buf1[50];
    char buf2[50];
    int iovcnt;
    struct iovec iov[3];
    strcpy(buf0,"MESSAGE=Hello World!");
    strcpy(buf1,"MESSAGE_ID=52fb62f99e2c4");
    strcpy(buf2,"PRIORITY=5");
    iov[0].iov_base = buf0;
    iov[0].iov_len = sizeof(buf0);
    iov[1].iov_base = buf1;
    iov[1].iov_len = sizeof(buf1);
    iov[2].iov_base = buf2;
    iov[2].iov_len = sizeof(buf2);
    iovcnt = sizeof(iov) / sizeof(struct iovec);
    int ret = sd_journal_sendv (iov, iovcnt);
    if ret(!=0)
        cout<<"sendv "<<strerror(ret)<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I have written "Hello world!", 52fb62f99e2c4, 5 for MESSAGE, MESSAGE_ID and PRIORITY respectively. but in journal I can see they are written as BLOB.

```
MESSAGE=[92B blob data]
MESSAGE_ID=[89B blob data]
PRIORITY=[91B blob data]
```

Comment: Unlike to many functions in libc, POSIX, etc., functions `sd_journal_*` **do not set errno**. From [documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/sd_journal_print.html): `The five calls return 0 on success or a negative errno-style error code. The errno variable itself is not altered.`. Use `int ret = sd_journal_sendv(...)`, and, in case `ret` becomes not 0, print `strerror(-ret)`.

Comment: Hey thanks @Tsyvarev, Now I am able to write in journal. I modified as below:
    strcpy(buf0,"stringval1");
    strcpy(buf1,"stringVal2");
    strcpy(buf2,"stringVal3");
to
    strcpy(buf0,"MESSAGE=Hello World!");
    strcpy(buf1,"MESSAGE_ID=52fb62f99e2c49d");
    strcpy(buf2,"PRIORITY=5");
While I am checking the journal these fields are coming as BLOB. Any clue why? below is snapshot from journal
MESSAGE=[92B blob data]
    MESSAGE_ID=[89B blob data]
    PRIORITY=[91B blob data]
    CODE_LINE=27

Comment: Do not post code into the comments, [edit] your question post instead. If the code actually resolves your problem, post an **answer** (on Stack Overflow self-answering is perfectly accepted).

Comment: I am not an expert in `sd_journal_*` functions, but this phrase `Note that this function will not strip trailing whitespace of the passed fields, but passes the specified data along unmodified.` in documentation seems to imply that data for `sd_journal_sendv` function are actually **binary data**, exactly as you observe. Looks like for passing strings the function `sd_journal_send` (without `v` suffix) should be used. See that blog for usage examples: http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/journal-submit.html.

Comment: thanks @Tsyvarev, I noticed when I tried to write statically created variables such as array, it is writing blob. but when I tried to write dynamically allocated variable(ex char*) it wrote text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't passing the sizes of your fields in `.iov_len`. This causes the 50-byte bufs to contain garbage at the end. `journalctl` shows those as blob data because it is invalid UTF-8.